# There is no Menu Option in my Android Studio (res>menu)

Tags: android

in my Android Studio there is no Menu option as (res>menu).how can create this menu and what can i do? please help

Comment: this is not a question, this is simple logic as if you are not able to find menu folder then right click on res folder and create new folder with name menu

Comment: Create new directory named **menu** under **res** by right-clicking on res.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no menu option, you have to create it

right click on `res-> New -> Directory -> Create Menu`

Answer (score 0):

`right click on res-> New -> Directory -> Create Menu`

after that

```
right click on Menu -> New -> Menu Resource File
```